# VS2010 - File New Menu is missing "New Project"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

A coworker just installed Visual-Studio-2010 Premium from MSDN.  The install acted like it worked fine, but when he clicks the "File" menu, he only has "new file".  On my installation, I see a "New" menu with a sub-menu that contains Projects, Files, Team Projects.

Any ideas of things to check or how to fix his installation.  I think he did a repair already.

Comment: I suspect you've installed the wrong version of VS - it sounds like you just have the VS shell but not any of the language/project support. Can you confirm which ISO you installed from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try Tools + Import and Export + Reset.  This will restore the menus to their factory settings.  This may be necessary when you just installed a new version of VS, as in this case, it imports the menus of the previous version of VS so everything looks familiar.  That is not always desirable.

If that doesn't pan out then the next step is to run devenv.exe with the /safemode command line option to ensure this isn't an add-in that's causing problems.

Comment: That's was amazingly simple - and it definitely fixed the problem.  Any idea why a clean install would require this?

Comment: The VS2010 installer tries to preserve menu, toolbar and keyboard customizations made in an earlier version so you'll get started with everything looking familiar.  That doesn't always seem to work correctly however.

Comment: Just had a similar problem here where a user previously had a Team Explorer installed. They uninstalled it and installed VS Premium, so presumably it was trying to retain the (minimal) preferences from Team Explorer. Resetting the options resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is long over due, but I was just having the same issue on 2013. For some reason, VS was debugging, and that was the reason a new project wasn't available. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. figured it out after reading this question.
If you set up visual studio default setting for Visual Basic it doesn't have a new menu but resetting to default settings for Visual C# added it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the first launch was clicked "project Management Setting" instead to click "General Development Setting" and missed NEW Project and Toolbox.

To fix, do the following

1. click Tools Menu
2. Click Import & Export Setting
3. Select Reset all setting --> Next
4. Next --> select "General Development Setting" --> Next