# How to open an existing project that is not a team project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have an instance of Visual Studio 2010 installed on a machine.  It is connected to a Team Foundation Server.  I would like to open a website project that is not on Team Foundation Server, however I can only open Team Projects or files.  The website is a folder.

Any tips?

Comment: think they are same.. do you get any error?  pls try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx

Comment: I have a File menu, but New is not an option.  I get New Team Project..., Connect to Team Project, New File..., Open File...

Comment: did you setup visual studio default setting for Visual Basic?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087034/vs2010-file-new-menu-is-missing-new-project

Comment: That was it.  The setup happened before I got the machine.  I changed the default settings to developer and the menus now make sense for me.  Thanks.

Comment: ah ok nice..i have added the comment as an answer now too :) pls if possible mark it as answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup visual studio default setting for Visual Basic??

[VS2010 - File New Menu is missing "New Project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087034/vs2010-file-new-menu-is-missing-new-project)